# introducing a landscape pdf in a portrait document

Tags: tables, pdf, pdfpages, landscape

After having examined multiple and different solutions for introducing large and complex tables in my document, and after many excellent and valuable suggestion from this StackExchange, the best arrangement I found is to compile a pdf file and insert it in the document.
My tables are large and, as they are written, do not fit on a portrait page. However, my document is portrait oriented. If I had to introduce the tables in the document directly I would have to make several changes (in fact the preamble of the tables files are different from the preamble of the document. However, I have hundreds of tables and it would not be practical. introducing a pdf allows me to keep the characteristics of the tables.
Oddly enough (at least for a newbie as I am), when I insert the pdf in the document the tables are nicely arranged on a portrait page (they did not fit on that orientation on the original file, neither they did if I placed any single table directly in the document) as in [image: this example]

I actually expected a landscape page inserted in a portrait document, but actually I do like this solution.
The question is: would it be possible to have more than one table on a single page (now the space seems to be available) instead than one table per page?
Here is a MWE for the landscape tables:

```
% This file was converted to LaTeX by Writer2LaTeX ver. 1.6.1
% see http://writer2latex.sourceforge.net for more info
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[style=vancouver,citestyle=numeric-comp,sorting=none,isbn=false,url=false,eprint=false, doi=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftex, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, pdftitle=, pdfauthor=Fabio Cesare Campanile, pdfsubject=, pdfkeywords=}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\arraybslash{\let\\\@arraycr}
\makeatother
% Page layout (geometry)
\setlength\voffset{-1in}
\setlength\hoffset{-1in}
\setlength\topmargin{2cm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{2cm}
\setlength\textheight{17.001cm}
\setlength\textwidth{25.201cm}
\setlength\footskip{0.0cm}
\setlength\headheight{0cm}
\setlength\headsep{0cm}
% Footnote rule
\setlength{\skip\footins}{0.119cm}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{-0.018cm}\setlength\leftskip{0pt}\setlength\rightskip{0pt plus 1fil}\noindent\textcolor{black}{\rule{0.25\columnwidth}{0.018cm}}\vspace*{0.101cm}}
% Pages styles
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ps@Standard{
  \renewcommand\@oddhead{}
  \renewcommand\@evenhead{}
  \renewcommand\@oddfoot{}
  \renewcommand\@evenfoot{}
  \renewcommand\thepage{\arabic{page}}
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{Standard}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1mm}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\title{}
\author{Fabio Cesare Campanile}
\date{2022-01-16}
\addbibresource{LGBiBiblio.bib}
\begin{document}


\begin{flushleft}

\begin{tabular}{|m{3.6139998cm}|m{7.1060004cm}|m{7.0880003cm}m{7.09cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|m{25.498001cm}|}{\textbf{Studio:} \fullcite{reynvo2014a}

}\\\hline
\textbf{Disegno dello studio}


\textbf{Livello di evidenza} &
\textbf{Dettagli dello studio/limitazione} &
\multicolumn{1}{m{7.0880003cm}|}{\textbf{Caratteristiche dei pazienti}} &
\textbf{Interventi}\\\hline
\textbf{Disegno dello studio:}

~

\textbf{metanalisi}

~
 &
\textbf{Paesi:} Non applicabile

\textbf{Centri:} Non applicabile

\textbf{Setting: }Non applicabile\textbf{ }

\textbf{Finanziamento}: Nessuno

\textbf{Tasso di dropout: }Non applicabile

\textbf{Limitazioni}: {indirectness (scarsa trasferibilità diretta dei risultati)}

\textbf{Critical appraisal: }AMSTAR II

~
 &
\multicolumn{1}{m{7.0880003cm}|}{Pazienti affetti da laparocele o ernia primaria (25 studi con 3868 pazienti)

~

\textbf{Ricerca bibliografica}: fino a novembre 2012

~

\textbf{Criteri di inclusione: tecnica }laparoscopica, stud includenti almeno 30 pazienti, follow up almeno di 12 mesi, lingia inglese, francese, spagnolo, tedesco

\textbf{Criteri di esclusione:} pazienti cirrotici, piccole ernie ventrali

~
} &
Tecnica lapaoroscopica IPOM di confronto fissaggio con tacks vs. fissaggio con sutura\\\hline
\textbf{Note}: &
\multicolumn{3}{m{21.683998cm}|}{~
}\\\hline
\textbf{Obiettivi} &
{}- recidiva erniaria &
\multicolumn{2}{m{14.378cm}|}{\textbf{Risultati: }

tacks + sutures: 2,5\% (95\% CI, 1,3-3,7\%)

~
}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}


\bigskip

\begin{flushleft}

\begin{tabular}{|m{3.6139998cm}|m{7.1060004cm}|m{7.0880003cm}m{7.09cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|m{25.498001cm}|}{\textbf{Studio:} \fullcite{sajid2013b}

}\\\hline
\textbf{Disegno dello studio}


\textbf{Livello di evidenza} &
\textbf{Dettagli dello studio/limitazione} &
\multicolumn{1}{m{7.0880003cm}|}{\textbf{Caratteristiche dei pazienti}} &
\textbf{Interventi}\\\hline
\textbf{Disegno dello studio:}

metanalisi &
\textbf{Paesi:} Non applicabile

\textbf{Centri:} Non applicabile

\textbf{Setting: }Non applicabile\textbf{ }

\textbf{Finanziamento}: Nessuno

\textbf{Tasso di dropout: }\textcolor[rgb]{0.13333334,0.13333334,0.13333334}{rischio di BIAS (follow up incompleto, case series), eterogeneità, imprecisione (bassa numerosità campionaria)}

\textbf{Critical appraisal: }AMSTAR II &
\multicolumn{1}{m{7.0880003cm}|}{Pazienti affetti da laparocele o ernia primaria

2 RTC, 2 Non RCT

207 pazienti

~

\textbf{Ricerca bibliografica}: fino a luglio 2012

~

\textbf{Criteri di inclusione: }RCT e studi osservazionali

\textbf{Criteri di esclusione:} } &
Tecnica lapaoroscopica IPOM di confronto fissaggio con tacks vs. fissaggio con sutura\\\hline
\textbf{Note}: &
\multicolumn{3}{m{21.683998cm}|}{~
}\\\hline
\textbf{Obiettivi} &
{}-durata tempo operatorio

{}-dolore post-operatorio

{}-complicanze post-operatorie

{}-durata della degenza

{}-recidiva erniaria &
\multicolumn{2}{m{14.378cm}|}{\textbf{Risultati: }

{}-Tack vs. sutura

{}-tempo operatorio: MD, -23.65; 95\% CI, -31.06, -16.25; p {\textless}0.00001

{}-dolore post-operatorio a 4-6 settimane: MD, -0.69; 95\% CI, -1.16, -0.23; p{\textless}0.004

{}-complicanze peri-operatorie: OR, 1.22; 95\% CI, 0.51, 2.92; p 0,65

{}-durata della degenza: MD, 0.07; 95\% CI, -0.14, 1.37, p 0,53

{}-recidiva erniaria OR, 1.54; 95\% CI, 0.38, 6.27; p 0,54

~
}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{flushleft}


\end{document}
```

and for the portrait document:

```
\documentclass[chapterprefix=true]{scrbook}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}%per inserire pdf multipagina
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}


\usepackage[style=vancouver,citestyle=numeric-comp,sorting=none,isbn=false,url=false,eprint=false, doi=false]{biblatex}



\definecolor{chaptergrey}{rgb}{0.7,0.7,0.7}

\let\raggedchapter\raggedleft
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont}
%\setkomafont{element}{commands}
\setkomafont{title}{\color{cyan}\LARGE}
\setkomafont{chapter}{\color{cyan}\LARGE}
\setkomafont{subtitle}{\color{black}}

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{%
    \scalebox{3}{\color{cyan}\thechapter}%
}


\begin{document}
    \author{}
    
    \subject{Linea Guida}
    \title{\textbf{Il trattamento laparoscopico di laparocele e ernie ventrali}}
    \subtitle{}
    \titlehead{}
    
    
    \date{Gennaio 2022}
    
    \frontmatter
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents

    
    
    
    \mainmatter

    \chapter{one}
    \section{Schede studi quesito 2D}
    \includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{MWEtabelle.pdf}

    
    

    

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\includepdfmerge[nup=1x2]{MWEtabelle.pdf, MWEtabelle.pdf}` instead of `\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{MWEtabelle.pdf}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `\includepdf` command to

```
\includepdf[pages=-,nup=1x2,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{MWEtabelle.pdf}
```

yields the following result.

[image: result with includepdf]

As you can see, both tables are included, but the result does not look very nice. You have no control over the spacing and the tables are inserted on a new page, leaving the prior page almost blank.

I would recommend to compile each table with the `standalone` document class. The resulting PDF will just contain the content without any margins. The code for the first table is:

Make sure to remove the `geometry` code.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[style=vancouver,citestyle=numeric-comp,sorting=none,isbn=false,url=false,eprint=false, doi=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftex, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue, filecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, pdftitle=, pdfauthor=Fabio Cesare Campanile, pdfsubject=, pdfkeywords=}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\arraybslash{\let\\\@arraycr}
\makeatother
% Footnote rule
\setlength{\skip\footins}{0.119cm}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{-0.018cm}\setlength\leftskip{0pt}\setlength\rightskip{0pt plus 1fil}\noindent\textcolor{black}{\rule{0.25\columnwidth}{0.018cm}}\vspace*{0.101cm}}
% Pages styles
\makeatletter
\newcommand\ps@Standard{
    \renewcommand\@oddhead{}
    \renewcommand\@evenhead{}
    \renewcommand\@oddfoot{}
    \renewcommand\@evenfoot{}
    \renewcommand\thepage{\arabic{page}}
}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{Standard}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1mm}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\title{}
\author{Fabio Cesare Campanile}
\date{2022-01-16}
\addbibresource{LGBiBiblio.bib}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{tabular}{|m{3.6139998cm}|m{7.1060004cm}|m{7.0880003cm}m{7.09cm}|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|m{25.498001cm}|}{\textbf{Studio:} \fullcite{reynvo2014a}
        
    }\\\hline
    \textbf{Disegno dello studio}
    
    
    \textbf{Livello di evidenza} &
    \textbf{Dettagli dello studio/limitazione} &
    \multicolumn{1}{m{7.0880003cm}|}{\textbf{Caratteristiche dei pazienti}} &
    \textbf{Interventi}\\\hline
    \textbf{Disegno dello studio:}
    
    ~
    
    \textbf{metanalisi}
    
    ~
    &
    \textbf{Paesi:} Non applicabile
    
    \textbf{Centri:} Non applicabile
    
    \textbf{Setting: }Non applicabile\textbf{ }
    
    \textbf{Finanziamento}: Nessuno
    
    \textbf{Tasso di dropout: }Non applicabile
    
    \textbf{Limitazioni}: {indirectness (scarsa trasferibilità diretta dei risultati)}
    
    \textbf{Critical appraisal: }AMSTAR II
    
    ~
    &
    \multicolumn{1}{m{7.0880003cm}|}{Pazienti affetti da laparocele o ernia primaria (25 studi con 3868 pazienti)
        
        ~
        
        \textbf{Ricerca bibliografica}: fino a novembre 2012
        
        ~
        
        \textbf{Criteri di inclusione: tecnica }laparoscopica, stud includenti almeno 30 pazienti, follow up almeno di 12 mesi, lingia inglese, francese, spagnolo, tedesco
        
        \textbf{Criteri di esclusione:} pazienti cirrotici, piccole ernie ventrali
        
        ~
    } &
    Tecnica lapaoroscopica IPOM di confronto fissaggio con tacks vs. fissaggio con sutura\\\hline
    \textbf{Note}: &
    \multicolumn{3}{m{21.683998cm}|}{~
    }\\\hline
    \textbf{Obiettivi} &
    {}- recidiva erniaria &
    \multicolumn{2}{m{14.378cm}|}{\textbf{Risultati: }
        
        tacks + sutures: 2,5\% (95\% CI, 1,3-3,7\%)
        
        ~
    }\\\hline
\end{tabular}
    
\end{document}
```

In your main document you can do something like

```
\section{Schede studi quesito 2D}
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{MWEStandalone.pdf}
\bigskip
    
\noindent\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{MWEStandalone2.pdf}
```

The result is

[image: standalone solution]

In my opinion, this approach is much better and gives you more control over the placement.

**Note** Your table code contains a lot of unnecessary packages and command definitions, which are probably created by `Writer2LaTeX`. I would recommend, that you write the tables in `LaTeX` yourself, giving you a lot more control. You might have a look at the [`tabularray`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package, which has a very flexible interface for creating tables.

**Edit**

If you want to use the first solution, you can also try

```
\includepdf[pages=-,nup=1x2, scale=0.9, pagecommand{\thispagestyle{plain}}]{MWEtabelle.pdf}
```

with a `scale` value provided. That could fix your overlapping page numbers.

Comment: I know and I agree that I should have written the tables myself. However, there are more than one hundred tables, written by many collaborators of mine, in word. It is almost impossible to do it.

Comment: if I understand correctly, you suggest to make one document for each table and then inserting each one in the main document. With more than one hundred tables it would be very time consuming and prone to errors

Comment: @FabioCampanile yes, that is what I meant. Maybe exporting each table with Writer2Latex could also work. Or are all tables in one document?

Comment: yes they are! In addition, using the first solution is not possible either because the absence of control to the sapcing includes the fact that the page number overlaps with the lower table, if it is a long one.

Comment: @FabioCampanile well, I think to achieve a good layout, you will have to split the tables either in Word in in LaTeX. Otherwise, you will unfortunately loose the structural information where each table is. ìncludpdf` just includes the pdf, but does not have access to strutural information, because that information is not present in the PDF.

Comment: @FabioCampanile if you know how do it, maybe writing a simple script (e.g. Pearl) could speed up splitting the tables into individual files.

Comment: @FabioCampanile I have made an edit to the answer. Maybe with this you can avoid the overlapping with the page numbers for the first solution.